# TypeScript: have a generic parameter but still check if it has a certain property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am slowly migrating a sizable SvelteKit application to TypeScript, and I am current working on the API layer. Here I have a function with two generics:

```js
// Either does a POST or a PUT
export function save<T, U>(basePath: string, data: U, token?: string): Promise<T> {
  if (data.id) {
    return put<T, U>(`${basePath}/${data.id}`, data, token);
  } else {
    return post<T, U>(basePath, data, token);
  }
}
```

The idea being that both the data and the result will be typed (inspiration from https://eckertalex.dev/blog/typescript-fetch-wrapper). So `data` is a generic `U` type, but I still want to check if it has an `id` property or not. How can this be done? Currently I get the error "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'U'" which makes perfect sense but I am not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a constraint to `U`.

```
export function saveApi<T, U extends { id?: string }>(fetch: Fetch, basePath: string, data: U, token?: string): Promise<T> {
  if (data.id) {
    return putApi<T, U>(fetch, `${basePath}/${data.id}`, data, token);
  } else {
    return postApi<T, U>(fetch, basePath, data, token);
  }
}
```